# For loop within p5.js and accessing array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```js
let position = []

function setup(){
let cnv = createCanvas(window.width,window.height);
  cnv.parent('canvas')
  noStroke()
  for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ;i++){
    let x = random(10,20)
    position.push(x)
  }
}
console.log(position[0])
function draw(){
  background('#fac81f')
  translate(width/2,height/2)
  ellipse(0,0,width/3)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I had hoped to access objects in the array with, for example.

```
console.log(position[0])
```

position[0] give me 'undefined' :( I would appreciate an explanation. Many thanks

Comment: _access objects in the array_ there are no objects in the array, there are numbers from 0 to 9. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Check your error log.  There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: Try `console.log(position)` after the loop.

Comment: This is your array: `Array [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]`. Isn't it what you expected?

Comment: What is wrong? This code will make an array as follows: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Doing `console.log(position[0])` will log `0`.

Comment: What is your expected result? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: *"But I can't :("* How are you saying it is not working? Do you get a traceback? Which JavaScript environment are you using? This code works in Google Chrome.

Comment: You can `push` your objects into `position` array and then access them like `position[0]`

Comment: I've made a snippet out of your code, check it out, it works.

Comment: You're not executing `setup()` anywhere, so the array is never populated.  Just put `setup();` before the `console.log` and it will work.

Comment: @Archer perhaps the hold can be lifted now that the question is clarified.

Comment: @Nishant Can the hold be lifted now?

Comment: @Noah, I voted for reopening as there is a fiddle now:) About the error,  from what I can see, `position` is never getting populated because the function that is supposed to populate is throwing some error.

Comment: @Nishant Solution is below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

```
let position = []

// This code only _declares a function called setup. It
// does not run the function.
function setup() {
  let cnv = createCanvas(window.width,window.height);
  cnv.parent('canvas')
  noStroke()
  for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ;i++){
    let x = random(10,20)
    position.push(x)
  }
}

// At this point, you have not added anything to
// position. It's a blank array, because `setup` has
// not been run.
console.log(position[0])
```

A solution might be to put your `console.log` inside the `setup` function.

```js
let position = []

function setup() {
  for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ;i++){
    let x = random(10,20)
    position.push(x)
  }

  console.log(position[0])

  let cnv = createCanvas(window.width,window.height);
  cnv.parent('canvas')
  noStroke()
}

function draw(){
  background('#fac81f')
  translate(width/2,height/2)
  ellipse(0,0,width/3)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.min.js"></script>
```

This way it only runs when `setup` is actually run.

Comment: I think OP knows that. Their code works, but for some reason, they say it doesn't

Comment: This question shouldn't have answers posted as there is nothing wrong with the code the OP posted.  Until they response there's nothing to answer.

Comment: @JeremyThille They wanted an explanation and here it is. Perhaps they don't know why they are just seeing `0`. This explains why.

Comment: Fair point, but actually all OP said is "But I can't :(", that's it, so we don't know what's wrong. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Archer They are mistaking their code for being broken, and asking for an explanation. I think it deserves one.

Comment: If it was broken I'd agree with you, but it is not.  This "answer" should not have been posted.  At most it should have been a comment.

Comment: Hi all apologies for the confusion, I am running the code inside the p5.js framework and getting undefined when I try to call the array. I will edit my original post for a better understanding of the question

Comment: @James I'm also able to do this in p5: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyVvVZ?editors=1111

Comment: Hi Noah thanks for your time, I've edited my code and the undefined appears now?

Comment: @James I have updated the answer.

Comment: @James Please choose it as a correct answer if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Noah, I thought as the array is pushed to a globally scoped variable, I would be able to access it outside the setup() function?

Comment: Yepp, you can. You can access `position` inside and outside `setup()`. That's not the issue. The issue is nothing is pushed to `position` until `setup()` actually runs. Try put the `console.log` in `draw()` and it will probably work too, assuming `draw()` is executed after `setup()`.